# Eclipse Photon - Eclipse Marketplace not launching

Tags: eclipse

I just installed Eclipse Photon. I migraded one project from Oxygen to it - everything is working fine.

The problem I noticed is that I cannot open the Eclipse Marketplace. Whenever I click on it, I get the loading circle for 1-2 seconds then nothing happens.

I also tried this on a completely new empty workspace (so no old .metadata) - same behavior.
I also restarted PC - didn't help.

Any ideas? Is it me only that has this problem or is it a bug due to the new version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I managed to find the problem and fix it. I went to:
Help -> About Eclipse IDE -> clicked on "Installation Details" -> tab "Configuration" -> Clicked on "View Error Log"

The default browser opened and there I noticed the following stack trace:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2018-06-28 10:38:21.036
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 16: file:/C:/Eclipse Photon/eclipse/configuration/
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:65)
```

It was the space character in the folder named by me: "Eclipse Photon". I renamed it to "EclipsePhoton" and the marketplace opened successfully.

**Short answer: Make sure you do not have any spaces in the Eclipse installation file path.**

Comment: See [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536385) Eclipse bug report

Comment: Kind of difficult when Windows likes everything in "Program Files"... :-(  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I had this problem with eclipse 2020-03. I installed it at "C:\eclipse_2020" now... I am not at all pleased with this but at least it's working. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Fixed it for me! but I wish eclipse die soon and rise again ahead of IntelliJ.

Answer (score 20):

I fixed the issue with the solution from this link: https://www.chrisguindon.com/post/marketplace-client-not-opening-in-photon/

Steps:

1. Go to Help > Install New Software
2. Paste the Marketplace Client update site url into the “Work with”
   field: http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/photon
3. Select the “EPP Marketplace Client” checkbox
4. Follow the wizard and restart your Eclipse to finish the
   installation.

Answer (score 2):

**Addition to actunderdc answer:**

He is right. There is a bug if there is a space in the installation path. If you want to install in the `Program Files` folder, you can use the windows shortnames.

Find the shortname of the folder in cmd by using `dir /X`. For `C:\Program Files` it is something like `PROGRAM~1`.

When you got the shortname, you can add the folowing at the top of your eclipse.ini File in the same directory of the eclipse.exe

`-launcher
C:\PROGRAM~1\eclipse\jee\photon`

Make sure to adjust it to your installation path. After you have done this, marketplace can be opened. But when I open `Help -> About -> Instalation Details -> Configuration` it shows me two -launcher parameters with the long and the short name. I don't know, if it could cause sideeffects.

I opened a Bugreport at [bugs.eclipse.org](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=537251).

Comment: +1 for the short name trick. It still shows two set of launcher parameters for me as well and it does not fix the problem for me though.

Answer (score 2):

Had similar problem, this is what I did:

NOTE: If you have any other firewall software then make sure to allow eclipse though it & also check if your computer's time is proper(else leave this).

> Open Eclipse  >
>   Help >
>   Install New Software.. >
>   Enter link in work with " http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/photon/ " >
>   (after lodaing) select the EPP Marketplace Client and install it

- I had error while installing it, I just allowed eclipse through firewall then marketplace client updated smoothly. Then I restarted eclipse and marketplace opened.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, none of the above helped.

After hours of searching, I found a working solution: enable theming under *Window - Preferences - General - Appearance*

I had this disabled, so Eclipse uses my GTK Theme (Arc dark) and looks better. 
But enabling it makes Marketplace start again.

The stacktrace in the Eclipse error log (*Window - Show View - Error Log*) contained a hint that lead me to the theming option.

Comment: Same (switching themeing off killing Marketplace) here on CentOS 7.5 :-/

Answer (score 1):

First when trying to use WindowBuilder (SWT) in Eclipse JEE 4.8 you must remove all spaces from your Eclipse folder name that contains all its files. This first step was discovered via link:

[Eclipse Photon - Eclipse Marketplace not launching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51075843/eclipse-photon-eclipse-marketplace-not-launching)

Secondly, is this link tells the second half of the mystery. If you go to:

http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.8/

you will see on the left hand side "show directory contents" which will have "repository.zip" file as last file of this expanded list. Download this (~39Mb). Note path to this file, then in eclipse click on "help" (last menu item), then click on "Install New Software...", then click "add", then click "archive" and go to path of saved "repository.zip" and select it. You will see square check box now indicates file to install.

I believe one must then click "continue" (check box already checked for WindowBuilder install item), then confirm when all files to be installed show are shown on screen, then finally click "finish". After the file is loaded in archive step I am not sure of the exact verbiage used for remaining steps but I believe what I have said is mostly accurate and after adding archive it will be self evident (piece of cake) what steps to follow. Finally to check if Window builder is installed go to (in top menu items) "file" then "new" then "other" and then finally scroll down list and WindowBuilder should be in this list, otherwise you landed a goose egg and something went wrong.

Comment: Oops, in my previous post forgot to mention that "taking spaces out of Eclipse folder name of file that contains all Eclipse files" affected "Eclipse Marketplace..." in help menu item as the spaces affect it from running which in turn stops WindowBuilder (SWT) from running.

Answer (score 0):

Change your folder name **eclipse photon** to **eclipsephoton** if any space in your folder name its not open Eclipse Marketplace

Comment: Which folder?? please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by changing the name of the folder where eclipse was installed, the name i had used for the folder had a space and that was precisely preventing the use of the market place in eclipse, i removed the space and it worked normally.

Answer (score -2):

For Ubuntu 20.04,

Just remove the spaces in your folder name of the eclipse folder and try closing and reopening the eclipse.It will works!!!