# Eclipse Marketplace doesn't open?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

I have troubles with my Eclipse Marketplace, as shown below is my .log, I couldn't find any solutions to my problem.

And I have no errors like in [Eclipse Photon - Eclipse Marketplace not launching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51075843/eclipse-photon-eclipse-marketplace-not-launching) (and spaces in installation path also).

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 21: file:/C:/Users/PinkShit/eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:65)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:318)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:252)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:161)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:494)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:204)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:433)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(AbstractContributionItem.java:446)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.lambda$2(AbstractContributionItem.java:472)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4118)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1052)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3931)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3534)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1170)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1059)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:667)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:597)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:656)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:592)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1498)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 21: file:/C:/Users/PinkShit/eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/
at java.net.URI.create(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.catalog.MarketplaceInfo.computeConfigurationAreaRegistryFile(MarketplaceInfo.java:445)
at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.catalog.MarketplaceInfo.createRegistryFile(MarketplaceInfo.java:408)
at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.catalog.MarketplaceInfo.load(MarketplaceInfo.java:341)
at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.catalog.MarketplaceInfo.getInstance(MarketplaceInfo.java:330)
at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.catalog.MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy.<init>(MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy.java:109)
at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.wizards.MarketplaceWizard.initializeCatalog(MarketplaceWizard.java:922)
at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.wizards.MarketplacePage.setVisible(MarketplacePage.java:831)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showStartingPage(WizardDialog.java:1220)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:576)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1096)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:783)
at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.openWizardDialog(AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.java:145)
at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.execute(AbstractMarketplaceWizardCommand.java:72)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:291)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:93)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
... 36 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 21: file:/C:/Users/PinkShit/eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
... 58 more
```

maybe someone has the same problem. **Edit:** added the missing Exception!

Comment: See https://www.chrisguindon.com/post/marketplace-client-not-opening-in-photon/

Comment: You have not included the nested exceptions ...